# Java regex URL for MockServer expectation

Tags: java, regex, url, url-parsing, mockserver

I'm trying to set up some expectations in MockServer where I have a specific expectation for requests matching this path

`/api/users/:user_id`

using the regex `/api/users/.*`.

However, I have a few other expectations which I want to match when accessing user-specific resources:

```
/api/users/:user_id/books
/api/users/:user_id/books/:book_id
/api/users/:user_id/holidays
```

I'm not really sure how to properly use regexs to match the first path, without also affecting the requests coming for the user-specific resources without (i.e., all requests are matching on the first path).

For example, I believe for the `/api/users/:user_id/books` path, I can use the regex `/api/users/.*/books`, but this will never match, because the regex `/api/users/.*` for the first path will always match these deeper URLs.

I've been reading [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), but can't quite figure out how to correctly use the regexes for this particular case

Comment: What values can `:user_id` take?  Or, are you trying to match the literal text `:user_id` ?

Comment: It takes any string with alphanumeric characters

Comment: From what I’ve gathered it seems ([^/]+) may do what I need

Answer (score 0):

One general approach here might be to use negative lookahead assertions.  For the general case, you could use this pattern:

```
/api/users/\d+/(?!books|holidays)
```

Then, for the more specific cases, use patterns which you already had in mind, e.g.

```
/api/users/\d+/books
/api/users/\d+/holidays
```

### Demo